# How to click on a tab with specific text?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I need to click on tab "Pis/Cofins" in my application

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabs">
    <li class="">
        <a href="#dados" aria-controls="home" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Dados Gerais</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#pisCofins" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">Pis/Cofins</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#combustivel" data-toggle="tab">Combustíveis</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#modoDeServir" data-toggle="tab">Modo de Servir</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#imagens" data-toggle="tab">Imagens</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#informacoes" data-toggle="tab">Informações</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may simply use the following xpath:

```
//a[text()='Pis/Cofins']
```

You may use extension like Firebug in firefox to easily find locators and use them in your test scripts

Answer (score 2):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to click on tab with text as **Pis/Cofins** you can use either of the following solutions:

- `LinkText`:

  ```
  driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Pis/Cofins")).Click();
  ```
- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("ul.nav.nav-tabs#tabs a[href$='pisCofins']")).Click();
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(@href,'pisCofins') and contains(.,'Pis/Cofins')]")).Click();
  ```

Comment: What is the point of making already submitted (and accepted) solution more complicated?! 1) No 100% guarantee that `By.LinkText("Pis/Cofins")` will work, 2) OP wants to select element *by specific text*. CSS selector contains no refer to text node, 3) XPath added no improvements to [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52282866/how-to-click-on-the-tab-with-text-as-pis-cofins-as-per-the-html-through-selenium/52282949#52282949)